# why password is not asked when output is shown in another terminal

Tags: terminal, password, tty

When i use:

```
date > /dev/tty3
```

the output is delivered to first cli terminal.

But my question is why does the terminal not ask for password.
We are using terminal for output, the command is delivered to terminal so how can the out is shown to us without asking password.

Comment: Whose password should it be asking?

Comment: we are using terminal tty3 for output of  command: date > /dev/tty3. so why terminal tty3 is not asking for password before showing the output of our command.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: _Why_ should it ask for a password if the current user has write-permissions to the other terminal? It would be akin to requiring a password for doing `cat >myfile` when I already have control over `myfile` (in fact, it is _exactly_ the same thing)

Answer (score 5):

Because you already have access to the terminal since it belongs to your user. For example:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/10

$ ls -l /dev/pts/10
crw--w---- 1 terdon tty 136, 10 Sep 16  2022 /dev/pts/10
```

So I own this. I now open a new terminal and run:

```
$ date > /dev/pts/10
```

And, as expected, it appears in my first terminal window. Now, if I open a terminal as `root` with `sudo xterm`, this is what I see:

```
[root@oregano terdon]# tty
/dev/pts/12
```

And if I try to write to that terminal as my regular user, I get:

```
$ ls -l /dev/pts/12
crw--w---- 1 root tty 136, 12 Sep 16 14:06 /dev/pts/12

$ date > /dev/pts/12
bash: /dev/pts/12: Permission denied
```

So there is no password request, but you can only write to terminals you have permission to write to.